Move max delivery count reached messages to error/new queue instead of dead letter - Mass transit Azure Service bus
We need a way to process the messages in the deadletter queue but Azure service bus explorer doesn't seem to support application/vnd.masstransit+json content type to resend the selected messages.
Few approaches were evaluated but a proper guide could not be found to go ahead with an approach.
Approach 1
Forward dead letter queue messages to a separate queue.
We couldn't find a solution in mass transit to set ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo in the IReceiveEndpointConnector level.
The below seems to be possible but we want it at the queue scope instead of the bus.
config.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
 {
   cfg.ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo = "queue-name";
 }

The below doesn't seem to be possible.
  IReceiveEndpointConnector handle = connector.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(subscriberName, (context, configurator) => {
    configurator.ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo = "queue-name"; //Not Possible
}

Approach 2
Use a (scheduled job) dead letter consumer to process the dead letter queue messages and push it back to the main queue to retry. Couldn't find a documentation on how to consume the dead letter sub queue of a queue.
Any solution for the above approaches or any other better approaches to re-process dead letter queue messages are appreciated.

MassTransit, by default, moves faulted messages to a separate queue named queue_error (where queue is your receive endpoint name). If you're getting messages in the Azure DLQ, it's likely due to a change in configuration, use of Azure Functions, or consuming directly from a subscription endpoint (in which you can't have a separate queue configured).
You can change the error queue name as shown in this video. The error queue usage is covers in this video.

Hi @Chris thank you for the response. I checked the above videos before posting the question and it didn't solve my question.  I am not directly consuming from a subscription endpoint and mass transit has created an error queue to submit faulted messages. However, when the messages reach the max delivery count it is moved to the dead letter queue instead of the error queue. Any config mistakes I am doing?
